# getting an exception when trying to initialize ApnsServiceBuilder

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I need a `.p12` file in order to authenticate with Apple's notification servers, and I have found some problems. As I understand, I need to generate the .csr and my private key identifying my machine. So I need to execute a command like this in my local machine:

```
*$:~/Escritorio/curro/certificados$ openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
```

writing new private key to 'privateKey.key'

Now, with my CSR.csr file, I need to login in to:

```
https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateCreate.action?formID=62653259
```

then I provide the .csr file generated before and the system 
gives me a .cer file (aps_development.cer) . Now, with this .cer file I have to generate it .p12 equivalent file. In order to do that, I need to make a .pem file starting from that .cer generated file from Apple. This is the command:

```
@Ubuntu:~/Escritorio/curro/certificados$ openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privateKey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
Enter Export Password:
Verifying
Enter Export Password:
```

After that I have a .p12 file and I need to initialize an ApnsService instance,

```
@Component
public class NotificationServer implements Runnable, BeanFactoryAware {

@Autowired
// APNS channel
private ApnsService serviceApns;
private String apns_payload;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
// build apns service path_to_apns_certificate, absolute path .p12 file 
String path_to_apns_certificate = config.getProperty("a-path");
//pass used to generate the .p12 file       
String password_apns_cert = config.getProperty("a-path");
log.debug("path_to_apns_certificate: " + path_to_apns_certificate);
//keep an eye with this!, this builder is non thread safe!
ApnsServiceBuilder apnsbuilder = new ApnsServiceBuilder();

String sMaxConections = config.getProperty("maxConections");
log.debug("sMaxConections: " + sMaxConections);
int maxConections = Integer.parseInt(sMaxConections);
apnsbuilder.asPool(maxConections );
String connectWithAppleApns = config.getProperty("apns.production");
log.debug("connectWithAppleApns: " + connectWithAppleApns);
apnsbuilder.withAppleDestination(new Boolean(connectWithAppleApns));
//here the exception is launched!       
apnsbuilder.withCert(path_to_apns_certificate, password_apns_cert);
serviceApns =apnsbuilder.build();       
}
}
```

**Here is the error message:**

```
Caused by: com.notnoop.exceptions.InvalidSSLConfig: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.newSSLContext(Utilities.java:88)
    at com.notnoop.apns.ApnsServiceBuilder.withCert(ApnsServiceBuilder.java:167)
    at com.notnoop.apns.ApnsServiceBuilder.withCert(ApnsServiceBuilder.java:134)
    at com.*****.agenda.utils.NotificationServer.init(NotificationServer.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
    ... 164 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1304)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.newSSLContext(Utilities.java:85)
    ... 174 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:355)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_40.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:462)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1295)
    ... 176 more
```

Can anyone give my any perspective on this?

Comment: I response myself. That error involves an error with the pass or the user, in my case the pass that was saved with quotes!! days without seen that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I response myself. That error involves an error with the pass or the user, in my case the pass that was saved with quotes!! days without seen that mistake.